# Extracting sublist from list of dicts of dicts with Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I work with Ansible. Given the following variable input, I am trying to extract the list of groups containing one user with Jinja2 syntax :

```
data:
  groups:
  - group: group1
    users:
      - id: user1
        email: user1@example.com
      - id: user2
        email: user2@example.com
  - group: group2
    users:
      - id: user4
        email: user4@example.com
      - id: user2
        email: user2@example.com
  - group: group3
    users:
      - id: user1
        email: user1@example.com
      - id: user3
        email: user3@example.com

lookup_user_id: user1
```

I would to find an expression that returns

```
groups:
  - group1
  - group3
```

If tried several things like the following :

```
- set_facts:
    groups: "{{ data | community.general.json_query( req ) }}"
  vars:
    req: 'groups[?contains(users[].id,"{{ lookup_user_id }}")].id'
```

or

```
- set_facts:
    groups: "{{ data | community.general.json_query( req ) }}"
  vars:
    req: 'groups[?contains(users,{"id":"{{ lookup_user_id }}"})].id'
```

But with no success.

I also tried to pre-process the initial variable, and transform 'data' into

```
data2:
  groups:
  - group: group1
    users:
      - user1
      - user2
  - group: group2
    users:
      - user4
      - user2
  - group: group3
    users:
      - user1
      - user3
```

because I think it would simplify my problem, but I wasn't able to find a way to do that.

Is there a way to achieve that ?